# Creating a .txt file in phonegap 2.0.0

Tags: html, cordova, forms, cordova-2.0.0

I am trying to add a function to an existing PhoneGap Build (Via Cordova 2.0.0) application.

The app has many existing functions, and this should have been a simple mod.

All I want to be able to do is write a simple HTML page with Cordova 2.0.0 FileWriter API (I think) to save notes as a .txt file (or it could be a .html file) Anything infact that I can then later upload to a PC and copy the text content into word documents/emails etc...

I have begun to use the Apache Cordova API at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter however  I am having a lot of difficulty understanding this.#

I have also looked at [Can't get Phonegaps FileWriter to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329010/cant-get-phonegaps-filewriter-to-work) however this doesnt look to have even been resolved...

Effectively this is the HTML file I am trying to use...

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <br>
    <input style="width:100%" class="center" type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Input File Name Here"><br>
    <textarea name="notes" class="center" style="width:100%" placeholder="Please Type Notes Here"></textarea><br>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><input style="width:100%" class="button-big" type="submit" name="save2" value="save"></td>
        <td><input style="width:100%" class="button-big" type="reset" name="clear2" value="clear"></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    <br>
    </form>
```

Its a simple HTML form, but I want some JS or something to make the save button save the file to the root with the filename+a predefined file extension (.txt or .htm or .html)

If anybody can help with this, it would be great

thanks,

Henry

Answer (score 1):

```
// create a file writer object
function CreateFileWriter()
{
    // request the file system object
    window.requestFileSystem( LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, OnFileSystemSuccess,fail);
}

function OnFileSystemSuccess( pFileSystemObj )
{
    console.log( pFileSystemObj.name );
    console.log( pFileSystemObj.root.name );

    var file_name = document.getElementById('filename').value;

    pFileSystemObj.root.getFile( file_name, {create: true, exclusive: false}, OnFileGetSuccess, fail);
}

function OnFileGetSuccess( pFileEntryObj )
{
    pFileEntryObj.createWriter( function(pWriterObj){ 
    gWriterObj  = pWriterObj; 
    }, fail );
}

function fail(evt)
{
    console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: will this use the form field to create the filename?

I need "file_name.txt" to be pulled from `<input style="width:100%" class="center" type="text" name="filename" placeholder="Input File Name Here">` is this possible?

Thanks, Henry

Comment: I've edited my answer, now it picks the value of your input control. Just provide the 'id' attribute to your control as you've given the name attribute. This should help you.